# InvalidArgumentError: input_1:0 is both fed and fetched, error with tensorflow, python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I am trying to run a code that tells me number of fall and non fall in fall detection of a human and i am getting an error :

> input_1:0 is both fed and fetch .

I tried running it alone but never works.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import scipy.io as sio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras 
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Lambda
from keras import backend as K
import cv2
def global_average_pooling(x):
return K.mean(x, axis = (2))
def global_average_pooling_shape(input_shape):
return input_shape[0:2]
p=Lambda(global_average_pooling, 
output_shape=global_average_pooling_shape)
X = sio.loadmat('/Users/fateh/Documents/Hamidreza Work/ConvFall/ts.mat')
X=X['Data']
import csv
with open('/Users/fateh/Documents/Hamidreza Work/ConvFall/lab.csv', 'r') as mf:
     re = csv.reader(mf,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
     re=np.array(list(re))
     label = re.astype(np.float64)
     Y_t=np.squeeze(label) 
nb_epochs = 3
y_train =Y_t[:158]
y_test =Y_t[158:]
x_train=X[:158]
x_test=X[158:]
nb_classes = len(np.unique(y_test))
batch_size = min(x_train.shape[0]/8, 16)
y_train = (y_train - y_train.min())/(y_train.max()-y_train.min())*(nb_classes-1)
y_test = (y_test - y_test.min())/(y_test.max()-y_test.min())*(nb_classes-1)
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)
x_train_mean = x_train.mean()
x_train_std = x_train.std()
x_train = (x_train - x_train_mean)/(x_train_std) 
x_test = (x_test - x_train_mean)/(x_train_std)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))
#x_train = np.transpose(x_train, (0, 2, 1))
#x_test = np.transpose(x_test, (0, 2, 1))
input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]
x = keras.layers.Input(x_train.shape[1:])
#    drop_out = Dropout(0.2)(x)
conv1 = keras.layers.Convolution1D(300, 9, padding='same')(x)
conv1 = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
conv1 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv1)
conv2 = keras.layers.Convolution1D(200, 5, padding='same')(conv1)
conv2 = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
conv2 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv2)
conv3 = keras.layers.Convolution1D(100, 3, padding='same')(conv2)
conv3 = keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
conv3 = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv3)
full = p(conv3)    
out = keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(full)
model = Model(input=x, output=out)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam() #'sgd'
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'loss', factor=0.5,
                  patience=500, min_lr=0.001) 
hist = model.fit(x_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epochs,
          verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, Y_test), callbacks = [reduce_lr])
predict = model.predict(x_test)
preds = np.argmax(predict, axis=1)
log = pd.DataFrame(hist.history)
print(log.loc[log['loss'].idxmin]['loss'], log.loc[log['loss'].idxmin]['val_acc'])
labels = {1:'Non-Fall', 2:'Fall'}
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(classification_report(preds, y_test,
                            target_names=[l for l in labels.values()]))
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(preds, y_test)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
res = plt.imshow(np.array(conf_mat), cmap=plt.cm.summer, interpolation='nearest')
for i, row in enumerate(conf_mat):
    for j, c in enumerate(row):
        if c>0:
            plt.text(j-.2, i+.1, c, fontsize=16)
#cb = fig.colorbar(res)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
_ = plt.xticks(range(2), [l for l in labels.values()], rotation=90)
_ = plt.yticks(range(2), [l for l in labels.values()])
inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functor = K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], outputs ) # evaluation function

# Testing
test=x_test[2:3,:,:]
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,:]
layer_outs = functor([test, 1.])
```

Trying to run this code used for letting you know the fall detection of files through deep Convolutional Neural Network, where radar data is used to collect raw data and processed.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the input layer,

```
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]]
```

if you still need it, you can add an identity function.

```
outputs.insert(0, K.identity(inp))
```